# Instantiating FormControl using ValidatorFn and AbstractControlOptions at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to instantiate `FormControl` using both `ValidatorFn` and `AbstractControlOptions` at the same time, as in the following example?

```js
new FormControl(null, Validators.required, { updateOn : 'change' });
```

Looking at the `form.d.ts` file, it doesn't seem possible:

```js
constructor(
  formState?: any,
  validatorOrOpts?:
    | ValidatorFn
    | ValidatorFn[]
    | AbstractControlOptions
    | null,
  asyncValidator?:
    | AsyncValidatorFn
    | AsyncValidatorFn[]
    | null
){}
```

However, as this is a pretty common requirement, I think it should be possible, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the below thing?

```js
new FormControl(null, {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'change'
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I overlooked the `validators` property

Comment: you are welcome, it's the `AbstractControlOptions` in constructor